# Minkowski distance in Tensorflow 2.0 for batched calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have two vectors `x` and  `xp`. I want to calculate Minkowski distance (e.g. calculate it at the infinity) in a Batch manner. I saw there is the method `tf.norm(.)`, with possibility to calculate different norms. But when I try e.g. calculate square distance between two vectors like `tf.norm(x-xp, axis=0, ord=2)` it does not work as intended.

Anyone know how to calculate Minkowski distance in Tensorflow 2.0 in a different way or somehow hijacking `tf.norm` method ?

Comment: can you post some code here?

Comment: Did you try changing the axis (0 --> 1)? Because the result will depend on you vector being a "row" or "column" vector. Anyway, the result of the ord=2 Minkowski norm is just the usual euclidean norm. Isn't it?